# docker-compose --scale number naming convention unexpected after multiple calls

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I use the `scale` flag the first time on a service called `app`:

```bash
docker-compose up -d --scale app=2 --no-recreate
```

and let's say, the existing container name is `app_1`, everything works as expected, I get my new container named `app_2`:

```bash
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
b35e7c28d564   app          "/app"           21 seconds ago   Up 18 seconds                                        
    app_1
a9d7bfa8dscc   app          "/app"           10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds                                        
    app_2
```

The problem is, if I remove the old app (`app_1`) and then rename `app_2` to `app_1`, when I run the `scale` command again, docker creates an `app_3`. How can this be? Is it possible that docker 'remembers' the original name of the container was `app_2`? How can I get it to use the expected `_1` and `_2` suffixes? Ideally, the goal is to get the following 3 commands to be infinitely repeatable:

```bash
docker-compose up -d --scale app=2 --no-recreate &&
docker rm -f app_1 &&
docker rename app_2 app_1
```

Is there a flag or something I can pass to the first command so that the names with `_1` and `_2` are always created? Or a better question, how or what does docker 'see' that it tries to create `_3` and `_4` and so on, even after removing and renaming any occurance of `_2` named containers?